How to bound this series over that set?
I am stuck with this exercise because I cannot understand how to proceed with the last request. It says to show that (first request)
$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-n-n^2}}{4^n} < \frac{1}{12e^5}$$
which I did. Indeed I studied the function $f(x) = e^{-x-x^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, finding that $f'(x) = e^{-x-x^2}(-1-2x) = 0 \iff x = -\frac{1}{2}$, which is the point of maximum.
Now $-\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{ 0; 1 \}$ and since the sequence $f_n = e^{-n-n^2}$ is strictly decreasing for $n \geq 0$, the maximum of $e^{-n-n^2}$ is reached at $n = 2$ (considering the series starts from $2$ indeed). Hence:
$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-n-n^2}}{4^n} < f(2) \sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} 4^{-n} = \frac{1}{12e^5}$$
Now I'm stuck on the second request, which asks for the same thing (bounding the series) but over the set $A = \mathbb{N} \setminus 2\mathbb{N}$.
How would I proceed with this? I understand that the sum would run through odd numbers only, that is $\sum_{n = 1, 3, 5, \ldots}^{+\infty}$ but I don't really know how to proceed...
Any help? Thank you!

@AnneBauval There is no specification about, but I believe we can choose it (perhaps we "should try" to find the best one?)

The sum over $\Bbb N\setminus2\Bbb N$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f(2k+1)}{4^{2k+1}}<\frac{f(3)}4\sum_{k=1}^\infty{16^{-k}}=\frac1{60e^{12}}.$$

Oh! Wow!! So simple in the end, and so brilliant... Thank you so much!
